# Create a conditional column based on aggregate value in other column

Tags: sql, sql-server, powerbi

I connected a query from SQL Server to Power BI, which contains columns such as Promo Year, submissionID, applicantID, Points Earned, Years in the program... no duplicates in the submissionid column, that is, a person can have many submissions and earn points for each one of those.

Goal: add a conditional column named Tier based on the sum of the earned points for each person in a specific year, for example, if a person earned 1,000 points in 2022 - this person should qualify for tier 2.

Comment: Can the tier to line up with the year?  For example if the row says 2022 do you want the tier to match the total for that user in 2022?

Comment: the tier would be a string value to classify the user. For example - Bob got 400 points in submission 1, 500 points in submission 2, and 300 points in submission 3 - all these submissions were in 2023. So total bob's points in 2023 is equal to 1200 points, what would make him part of tier 3 ( > 1000 points and < 1500 points). So in the tier column, we would see 'tier 3'.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know much about PowerBI, but if you could modify the SQL Query that you're using as your source, you might be able to add a window function to give you what you need.

```
SUM(points_earned) OVER (PARTITION BY Promo_Year, ApplicantID) AS TOTAL_ANNUAL_POINTS
```

Then this would give you the number you need to apply your case statement to it and show your tiers.

Your data would not be grouped, but the new column would. So your final result would look like this:

```
+------+--------------+------------+--------+---------------------+------+
| User | SubmissionID | Promo_Year | Points | TOTAL_ANNUAL_POINTS | Tier |
+------+--------------+------------+--------+---------------------+------+
| Bob  |     17744717 |       2022 |    900 |                1600 |    2 |
| Bob  |      8747631 |       2022 |    700 |                1600 |    2 |
| Bob  |     19951776 |       2023 |    400 |                2200 |    3 |
| Bob  |     15807081 |       2023 |   1500 |                2200 |    3 |
| Bob  |     13735534 |       2023 |    300 |                2200 |    3 |
+------+--------------+------------+--------+---------------------+------+
```

Comment: Yea, I thought about it. But there are other columns that I will need the data without being grouped by. I need a way to create an conditional column (Tier) based on the aggregate function SUM applied to Points in a table in power bi.

Comment: Window functions isn't the same as group by aggregates

Answer (score 1):

Let's say your table structure looks like this:

[image: SQL-Server]

And you imported it into POWER BI successfully.

Then you need to add a calculated column and use this DAX Code to achieve your goal:

```
Which_Tier? = 
VAR Total = CALCULATE(
        SUM(Submission[PointsEarned]),ALLEXCEPT(Submission,Submission[PromoYear],Submission[applicantID])
)
RETURN
SWITCH(
    TRUE(),
    Total < 500,"TIER_1",
    Total < 1000,"TIER_2",
    Total < 1500,"TIER_3",
    "TIER_4"
)
```

Then If we check what outcome it returns on our PBI screen:

[image: EndResult]